How to efficiently replace the Paterson-Stockmeyer algorithm and reduce non-scalar multiplications
Paterson-Stockmeyer algorithm
If we need to compute a high-degree polynomial expression, such as:
$$
P(y) = \sum_{k=0}^{B} a_k y^k
$$
the Paterson-Stockmeyer algorithm can process the powers in segments to reduce the number of non-scalar multiplications required for evaluating the polynomial.
Skill
The polynomial is decomposed into combinations of lower and higher powers. We choose suitable segment sizes $L $ and $H $ such that
$$
B = L \times H - 1
$$
Then, we first compute all lower powers $ y^j $ (where $ j < L $), followed by the higher powers, specifically multiples of $y^{iL} $.
and
$$ L \approx \sqrt{2(B + 1)}. $$
We start by computing the low powers
$$ \langle y \rangle^2, \langle y \rangle^3, \dots, \langle y \rangle^{L-1} $$
and the high powers
$$ \langle y \rangle^L, \langle y \rangle^{2L}, \langle y \rangle^{3L}, \dots, \langle y \rangle^{(H-1)L} $$
Then, the intersection polynomial can be rewritten as
$$ P(\langle y \rangle) = \sum_{i=0}^{H-1} \langle y \rangle^{iL} \sum_{j=0}^{L-1} a_{iL+j} \langle y \rangle^j, $$
where $a_k$ is the $ k $-th coefficient of $ P $.
The internal sums can be computed by scalar multiplications and additions from the low powers.
Non-scalar multiplications are only needed to multiply these internal sums by the high powers.
The total computation complexity of computing $ P(\langle y \rangle) $ is equal to
$$ L - 2 + 2(H - 1) = L + 2H - 4 $$
non-scalar multiplications.
The minimal non-scalar complexity $ O(\sqrt{B}) $ is achieved when
$$ L \approx \sqrt{2(B + 1)}. $$
I want to find more solution about how to Efficiently Replace the Paterson-Stockmeyer algorithm and reduce non-scalar multiplications,Is it possible to combine null polynomial theory and Newton interpolation theory for computational optimization? If there is an answer, I would be very grateful.

I don't understand your question, but iirc Paterson-Stockmeyer showed that $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ multiplications are necessary and sufficient for evaluation of $\deg f = n$ polynomials, e.g. this works for every such polynomial, and there are polynomials for which one requires $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ non-scalar multiplications. Does this answer your question? If not, could you phrase more precisely how you are hoping to improve on Paterson-Stockmeyer?

Thank you! I’ve already reviewed the proof of the necessary and sufficient conditions for the Paterson-Stockmeyer algorithm. Actually, I’m a bit confused myself. I’m mainly thinking about whether there might be some polynomial optimization techniques that could filter out faster computation methods under certain settings of ( (n, L, B) ). This is primarily based on some thoughts inspired by https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1364 , but I’m sorry that I’m not yet able to clearly describe the specific optimization steps.

There are faster methods if you focus on a specific prescribed polynomial and you allow precomputation to find an optimal algorithm. The idea is based on selecting linear combinations that contain many coefficients of the required product; for a starting point see Sastre, Ibañez Efficient Evaluation of Matrix Polynomials beyond the Paterson–Stockmeyer Method .
(Ultimately, I think that the problem can be recast as a tensor rank computation; you can review the techniques in algebraic complexity theory for sub-cubic matrix product and I believe some will apply to this problem.)

Thank you for providing this information! I'll take a deeper look .
